# Testing repository which map objects from files

Tags: java, spring, testing

how can I test in memory repository which is reading objects from JSON files in resource folder?

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public class MyRepository{

    private TreeMap<String, MyObject> objects;
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    public MyRepository(ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws IOException {
        // mapping objects from /resources to TreeMap
    }

    // some custom methods working on my objects

}
```

Now I want to test these methods, but I dont want to use "real" objects. What is the best way to test it? Should I create some constructor that would take some collection of objects as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how far you want to take your testing. You will need to perform a cost-benefit analysis on the risk involved in the code. There is risk of bugs in serializing and writing files, but the highest risk area of the code could be manipulation that the methods are doing. It just depends on code complexity

In the example you gave where you just pass in a list of objects, it will only test the logic within the methods, but it will not test the serialization and writing from in-memory to JSON files.

If you want to include testing on the serialization and writing to files, you can pass in a parameter that gives a directory where the files are located. By default, it will assume /resources. In your test, you can create a `@Before` where a directory is copied or created at a specific location, and then the path is passed into the repository during the test. While this is better in the sense that it has higher code coverage, it may not be beneficial if the serialization is very simple.

Comment: So in my case, if i just care about test the logic in my methods, creating constructor just for tests which takes prepared objects (not created from JSON files) is good approach?

Comment: It's a good --enough-- approach. People can take testing too far and waste valuable time to get 100% code coverage when there is little to no benefit.